# jetpack compose: scroll to bottom listener (end of list)

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-lazy-column

I am wondering if it is possible to get observer inside a `@Compose` function when the bottom of the list is reached (similar to `recyclerView.canScrollVertically(1)`)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 23):

For me the best and the simplest solution was to add `LaunchedEffect` as the last item in my `LazyColumn`:

```
LazyColumn(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
    items(someItemList) { item ->
        MyItem(item = item)
    }
    item {
        LaunchedEffect(true) {
            //Do something when List end has been reached
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the simplest and most elegant solution.
Are there any drawbacks?
From what I see in docs of LaunchedEffect the started coroutine will be cancelled when LaunchedEffect leaves composition.

Comment: Hmm, I didn't know that. I used it to load the next items page from api to do this I just launch a new coroutine from `LaunchedEffect`(by viewModel of course) and it works well, so this is the solution if you had such a problem. Nevertheless, that's a good point

Comment: This is elegant but has a drawback when using infinite loading since the LaunchedEffect will continue to fire when you scroll past the same item in the list multiple times. Unless you invalidate it with some logic manually.

Comment: Another drawback is when the last item is immediately visible, e.g. when your items list is loaded from network before they are populated the last item already fires.

Comment: This doesn't seem right. This effect also launches for the first time without even scrolling because just adding items to the list doesn't mean it's necessarily scrolled to the bottom or even items are visible on the screen.

Answer (score 19):

you can use `rememberLazyListState()` and compare

```kotlin
scrollState.layoutInfo.visibleItemsInfo.lastOrNull()?.index == scrollState.layoutInfo.totalItemsCount - 1
```

**How to use example**:

First add the above command as an extension (e.g., `extensions.kt` file):

```kotlin
fun LazyListState.isScrolledToEnd() = layoutInfo.visibleItemsInfo.lastOrNull()?.index == layoutInfo.totalItemsCount - 1
```

Then use it in the following code:

```kotlin
@Compose
fun PostsList() {
  val scrollState = rememberLazyListState()

  LazyColumn(
    state = scrollState,),
  ) {
     ...
  }

  // observer when reached end of list
  val endOfListReached by remember {
    derivedStateOf {
      scrollState.isScrolledToEnd()
    }
  }

  // act when end of list reached
  LaunchedEffect(endOfListReached) {
    // do your stuff
  }
}
```

Comment: It is triggering when the the item is at top too.

Answer (score 10):

Starting from `1.4.0-alpha03` you can use [**`LazyListState#canScrollForward`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/lazy/LazyListState#canScrollForward()) to check if you are at the end of the list.

Something like:

```
val state = rememberLazyListState()
val isAtBottom = !state.canScrollForward

LaunchedEffect(isAtBottom){
    if (isAtBottom) doSomething()
}
```

---

Before this release you can use the **`LazyListState#layoutInfo`** that contains information about the visible items. Note the you should use `derivedStateOf` to avoid redundant recompositions.

Use something:

```
@Composable
private fun LazyListState.isAtBottom(): Boolean {

    return remember(this) {
        derivedStateOf {
            val visibleItemsInfo = layoutInfo.visibleItemsInfo
            if (layoutInfo.totalItemsCount == 0) {
                false
            } else {
                val lastVisibleItem = visibleItemsInfo.last()
                val viewportHeight = layoutInfo.viewportEndOffset + layoutInfo.viewportStartOffset

                (lastVisibleItem.index + 1 == layoutInfo.totalItemsCount &&
                        lastVisibleItem.offset + lastVisibleItem.size <= viewportHeight)
            }
        }
    }.value
}
```

The code above checks not only it the last `visibile item == last index` in the list but also if it is fully visible (`lastVisibleItem.offset + lastVisibleItem.size <= viewportHeight`).

And then:

```
val state = rememberLazyListState()
var isAtBottom = state.isAtBottom()
LaunchedEffect(isAtBottom){
    if (isAtBottom) doSomething()
}

LazyColumn(
    state = state,
){
  //...
}
```

Comment: Did you mean `val isAtBottom = !state.canScrollForward`? If the list cannot scroll forward, then it's at the bottom.

Comment: @dannyroa Sorry my bad. Answer updated.

Comment: `canScrollForward` fires multiple times in my experience, as the UI is being loaded/rendered

Answer (score 5):

I think, based on the other answer, that the best interpretation of `recyclerView.canScrollVertically(1)` referred to bottom scrolling is

```kt
fun LazyListState.isScrolledToTheEnd() : Boolean {
    val lastItem = layoutInfo.visibleItemsInfo.lastOrNull()
    return lastItem == null || lastItem.size + lastItem.offset <= layoutInfo.viewportEndOffset
}
```

Comment: With this solution `isScrolledToTheEnd()` is true when the bottom of the last item has been viewed, whereas the other answer only needs a part of the last item to be visible. This is important when the last item is large enough that it can't all fit in the view.

Comment: I think the condition should be updated to 
`lastItem == null || (lastItem.index == layoutInfo.totalItemsCount - 1 && lastItem.size + lastItem.offset <= layoutInfo.viewportEndOffset)`

Answer (score 0):

Use `canScrollForward` to detect the end of scrollable list and `firstVisibleItemIndex > n` to make sure that event triggered when there are scrollable items in the list..

```
val lazyListState = rememberLazyListState()

LaunchedEffect(lazyListState.canScrollForward) {
    if (lazyListState.canScrollForward.not() && lazyListState.firstVisibleItemIndex > 1) {
                Log.i(TAG, "scroll-end")
    }
}

LazyColumn(state = lazyListState){
...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Simply use the `firstVisibleItemIndex` and compare it to your last index. If it matches, you're at the end, else not. Use it as `lazyListState.firstVisibleItemIndex`

Answer (score -1):

Found a much simplier solution than other answers. Get the last item index of list. Inside itemsIndexed of lazyColumn compare it to lastIndex. When the end of list is reached it triggers if statement. Code example:

```
LazyColumn(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize(),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
        itemsIndexed(events) { i, event  ->
            if (lastIndex == i) {
                Log.e("console log", "end of list reached $lastIndex")
            }
        }
     }
```

Comment: Won't work if you have more than one type of item